# HDFS command line put throwing an exception

Tags: command-line, hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I am trying to put a file into hdfs using ssh from my client pc to the NameNode server. There are 2 machines: One NameNode and one DataNode. Here is the command I am trying;

```
$ bin/hadoop fs -fs hdfs://MY_IP:MY_PORT -put example.txt example.txt
```

But it throws an exception. The logs say;

```
2013-05-23 09:25:31,808 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:_my_user_name_ cause:java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
2013-05-23 09:25:31,808 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on _my_port_, call getProtocolVersion(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol, 61) from _ip_:_port_: error: java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.getProtocolVersion(DataNode.java:1759)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

What can be the problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your core-site.xml file and verify the hdfs url.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your client's hadoop and cluster's hadoop, my guess is your client version is less than the cluster version.

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.getProtocolVersion(DataNode.java:1759)
```